# No route found for "GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Symfony 6

Tags: php, apache, symfony, .htaccess, routes

Browser does not open the route, and gives an error, only the sonata-admin page opens,

php bin/console debug:router shows:

`_preview_error   ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}`,

.htaccess is in public folder,

and here is the virtual host code:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/Codeing/Symfony/Avetaber.am/public"

    <Directory "D:/Codeing/Symfony/Avetaber.am/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "D:/Codeing/Symfony/Avetaber.am/src/Error/avetaber.am-error.log"
    CustomLog "D:/Codeing/Symfony/Avetaber.am/src/Error/avetaber.am-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm already giving up, please help

Comment: try clear cache using `php bin/console cache:clear`, set environment `APP_ENV=dev`, check error.log or access.log